# Different app name in play store

Tags: android, google-play

When listing an app in the play store, is it possible to have it dynamically change on the listing based on the language where listing is currently being viewed?  If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried setting your application name to `@string/app_name` and define `app_name` in each `strings.xml` that you have?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't change the actual listing name on google play.  When creating an up for upload in the developer console, I could not find a place to specify language changes for the app name.

Answer (score 0):

At shore-listing in google play developer console, you can add different language Title, Description and Screenshots.